# How to get the value of an input button using this in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks in advance for helping

Inside a function in a script, I'm trying to get the value of a button when it's clicked.
I just can't figure out the usage of "this" in that case.
There are a certain number of buttons in the page and several functions attached to them so I don't want to do jQuery('.A1').val() in the function each time a button is clicked.
I want the function to detect which button is clicked and its value

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.dosomething = function(){
        var currentval = $(this).val();
        console.log(currentval);
    };
});
</script>

<INPUT type="button" class="A1" value="blabla" onclick="jQuery().dosomething()"/>
```

The console returns 'undefined'

Thank you for your help
Dom

Comment: Why are you using inline js when you could use a nice pretty event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass current object `this` to the function like

```
<INPUT type="button" 
   class="A1" value="blabla"
   onclick="jQuery(this).dosomething()"/>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/92SWG/)

**EDIT**

Why are you using inline `onclick`? You can bind event to element also like

```
$(".A1").on("click", function () {
    jQuery(this).dosomething();
})
```

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/92SWG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jquery click function rather than the on click inline HTML call.
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

With `$.fn.dosomething = function()`, you have defined a plugin that can be called on a jquery object, but you pass nothing into jquery to serve as `this`.

Try:

```
onclick="jQuery(this).dosomething()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

We can bind the function on particualr event for particular element.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.dosomething = function(cthis){
        var currentval = $(cthis).val();
        alert(currentval);
        console.log(currentval);
    };

    $( "#myId" ).bind( "click", function() {
        jQuery().dosomething(this);
    })
});
</script>
<INPUT id="myId" type="button" class="A1" value="blabla"  />
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9NWc9/)

I think, the `this` inside the `$.fn.dosomething` refers itself rather than clicked button.